# exponential distribution of an exponential variable

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

> Given a random variable Y has an exponential distribution with mean 2.
>   Let $h(y) = \exp(-Y)$. How could I find $P[h(y) \leq 0.35]$?

For $Y$, I think $f(y, \beta) = \frac{1}{\beta} \exp(-y/\beta) = \frac{1}{2} \exp(-2y)$, but am not sure how to find $P[h(Y)\leq 0.35]$.

Could anyone please explain how to go about this question?

Comment: [For some basic information about writing math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)
at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editikng how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The function $\exp(-2y)/2$ is not a PDF on $y>0$, the function $\exp(-y/2)/2$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y \sim {\cal E}(\lambda)$ with $\lambda>0$.
Then $E[Y] = \lambda^{-1} = \beta$.

- The density function is $f(y, \beta) = \exp(-y/\beta)/\beta$ for every $y \ge 0$ and $\beta > 0$.
- The distribution function is $F(y,\beta) = 1-\exp(-y/\beta)$ for every $y \ge 0$ and $\beta > 0$.

In this question, $\beta = 2$ and $\lambda = 1/2$, hence
\begin{align}
\Bbb{P}(\exp(-Y) \le 0.35)
&= \Bbb{P}(Y \ge -\log0.35) \\
&= \exp(-(-\log0.35)/2) \\
&= \exp(\log\sqrt{0.35}) \\
&= \sqrt{0.35} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{7}{20}}
\end{align}